# GLSL, literal constant Input Layout Qualifiers

Tags: opengl, struct, glsl, constants

I wonder if I may have something like this:

```
layout (location = attr.POSITION) in vec3 position;
```

Where for example `Attr` is a constant structure

```
const struct Attr
{
    int POSITION;
} attr = Attr(0);
```

I already tried, but it complains

> Shader status invalid: 0(34) : error C0000: syntax error, unexpected
>   integer constant, expecting identifier or template identifier or type
>   identifier at token ""

Or if there is no way with structs, may I use something else to declare a literal input qualifier such as `attr.POSITION`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GLSL has no such thing as a `const struct` declaration. It does however have compile time constant values:

```
const int position_loc = 0;
```

The rules for [constant expressions](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Integral_Constant_Expression) say that a const-qualified variable which is initialized with a constant expression is itself a constant expression.

And there ain't no rule that says that the type of such a const-qualified variable must be a basic type:

```
struct Attr
{
  int position;
};
const Attr attr = {1};
```

Since `attr` is initialized with an initialization list containing constant expressions, `attr` is itself a constant expression. Which means that `attr.position` is an constant expression too, one of integral type.

And such a compile-time integral constant expression can be used in [layout qualifiers](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_%28GLSL%29), but only if you're using GLSL 4.40 or ARB_ehanced_layouts:

```
layout(location = attr.position) in vec3 position;
```

Before that version, you'd be required to use an actual literal. Which means the best you could do would be a `#define`:

```
#define position_loc 1
layout(location = position_loc) in vec3 position;
```

Now personally, I would never rely on such integral-constant-expression-within-struct gymnastics. Few people rely on them, so driver code rarely gets tested in this fashion. So the likelihood of encountering a driver bug is fairly large. The `#define` method is far more likely to work in practice.

Comment: Ok, I'll stick with `#define`